# why thread id get so large

Tags: python, linux, multithreading

```
In [19]: threading.currentThread().ident
Out[19]: 139639576676096
```

139639576676096 is my thread id in mysql CENTOS box. Is it OK?
why the thread id gets so big?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The thread identifier is not an auto-incrementing number. Instead, it is a *unique* number for that thread, and it is going to be a non-zero integer between `-sys.maxint + 1` and `sys.maxint`,

The identifier is a 'magic cookie' value. You don't need to care about it's actual value, just that it'll uniquely identify the current thread.